# How to preserve original files sequence when using list.files in R

Tags: r, file, fread

I use this command to get all files from all subfolders of the root folder:

```
SF <- list.files(rootpath, recursive=T, pattern=paste(".csv"))
```

The problem is that SF sorts files by name so that it's impossible to figure out the subfolder that the file belongs to:

```
Subfolder A:
  1.csv
  2.csv

Subfolder B:
  1.csv
  2.csv
```

The output is:

SF : 1.csv, 1.csv, 2.csv, 2.csv

However, I need to get this:

SF : 1.csv, 2.csv, 1.csv, 2.csv

Comment: Add `full.names=TRUE`?

Comment: see `?list.files`  e.g. `include.dirs` 
logical. Should subdirectory names be included in recursive listings?

Comment: full.names=TRUE works fine